# vim not starting in bash shell

Tags: bash, vim, freebsd

My terminal(FREE BSD) uses CShell by defualt , under which vim is working fine . But to run some testscripts , i have to use bash shell ,where some of my env variables are defined . Once i am in bash shell , if i start vim , it thorws this error

```
/libexec/ld-elf.so.1: Shared object "libgtk-12.so.2" not found, required by "vim"
```

vi is working fine though.Can some one help me solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plausible explanation is that depending on which shell you're running, you have different environment variable settings. Compare the output of

```
echo $PATH
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

under bash and under csh. Maybe `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` includes the location of `libgtk-12.so.2` when you're in csh but not when you're in bash. Or maybe `$PATH` leads to a different `vim` executable in csh and in bash (one that requires gtk in bash, and one that doesn't require gtk in csh). To check this, run `type vim` under bash and `which vim` under csh.

**EDIT**: based on your comments, there's a `vim` in `/volume/perl/bin/vim` that doesn't work for you, but you also need something in `/volume/perl/bin` to come first in the `PATH`, probably `perl`. You have several solutions:

- Put `/volume/perl/bin/vim` first in `$PATH`, and put `alias vim=/usr/local/bin/vim` in your `.bashrc` and your `.cshrc`.
- Don't put `/volume/perl/bin/vim` in `$PATH` at all, but arrange to run the perl scripts with `/volume/perl/bin/vim` instead of your local perl.
- Don't put `/volume/perl/bin/vim` in `$PATH` at all. Instead, put `~/bin` first in `$PATH`, and create symbolic links to what you need from `/volume/perl/bin` in `~/bin`, e.g., `ln -s /volume/perl/bin/perl ~/bin`.
- Try setting `PERL5LIB` and not `PATH`, in case what you need is not a newer version of perl but some extra libraries. E.g. `setenv PERL5LIB /volume/perl/lib/perl/5.10` (adjust to whatever directories are needed; you can see the default directories for `/volume/perl/bin/perl` by running `/volume/perl/bin/perl -le 'map print, @INC'`).
- Upgrade your perl so that your scripts works with them (perhaps in addition to the previous suggestion).
- Install the libraries that `/volume/perl/bin/vim` needs.
- Remove `vim` from `/volume/perl/bin`.

Whatever you do, I don't recommend to have different `PATH` settings in different shells, it gets confusing very quickly (as you've already noticed). Set `PATH` in `.login` (assuming `csh` is your login shell, otherwise in `.profile`).

Comment: yes.my $PATH has a few extra pathes to perl libraries which is creating the problem as you can see in my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

You mention terminal, but the library that it's complaining about is a GUI library.  Do you care about GUI?  if not, you may be able to force no gui and not attempt to load this lib, but I'm far from a vim guru.  You can even unset your DISPLAY, and vim will have to run in terminal mode.

As other's have answered, it's probably your LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or you're using a different vim than you're thinking.  See what's set in both bash and csh., and the differences

Also try the `ldd` command, it will show you what libraries your app is able to load.  it should fail on bash to resolve

On many systems, vi and vim are two separate installs, vim more featured for general editing, and a slimmed down, very few dependency version called vi for emergency mode.  I'm sure vi will work in either.